# Constructor of factory-like smart contract keeps reverting

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm working with 2 contracts, one that manages users bets for a specific football match and another (factory style) that generates these individual contracts to be managed separately.

The Generator contract is this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Generator {
    address immutable public owner;
    string public matchGenerated;
    Management[] public bettingHistory;

    constructor(string memory _league, string memory _match) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        matchGenerated = string(abi.encodePacked(_league, "_", _match));
        Management newBetContract = new Management(address(this));
        bettingHistory.push(newBetContract);
    }
}
```

The Management contract receives data from the Generator to define the manager and the match values, as follows (short version):

```
contract Management {
    address payable immutable public manager;

    string public matchDispute;
    
    Generator generator;

    constructor(address _contract) {
        generator = Generator(_contract);
        manager = payable(generator.owner());
        matchDispute = generator.matchGenerated();
    }
```

Once I try to deploy the Generator contract in Remix it results in a reverting error. If I remove the instance of the generator in the Management contract and repeat the constructor arguments in both contracts it works, but I want to avoid the redundancy and get the values already stored in the Generator variables automatically.

Comment: Are the two contracts in the same file? If not, you will have a cyclic import problem. But you did say it worked if you remove the instance of generator in Management. Can you try and remove the line "generator = Generator(_contract);" and change the next two lines to "manager = payable(Generator(_contract).owner());" and "matchDispute = Generator(_contract).matchGenerated();" to see if it worked. A better solution will be to create an IGenerator interface to expose the methods you need and import/use that in Management. You will then use "manager = payable(IGenerator(_contract).owner());"

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the SO community. 

Even though an EVM error about transaction reverted is usually quite generic from what I know of, it would be nice-to-have in your question, for search purposes.

Comment: @AlexandreGomes Thanks for the welcoming! In Remix it returns:

```creation of BetGenerator errored: VM error: revert.

revert
 The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. ```

Comment: @falopsy Thanks for the answer. Both contracts are in the same file. Just tried your suggestion removing the generator line and adjusting the following, but got the same result. I'm not very familiar with interfaces but I've checked that they don't allow variables declaration and I want to store in the Generator all those contracts deployed.

Comment: @TG555, see my comment below expanding on how to use interface for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the above using interface, your solution will be like:

Generator.sol file

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Generator {
    address immutable public owner;
    string public matchGenerated;
    Management[] public bettingHistory;

    constructor(string memory _league, string memory _match) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        matchGenerated = string(abi.encodePacked(_league, "_", _match));
        Management newBetContract = new Management(address(this));
        bettingHistory.push(newBetContract);
    }
}
```

IGenerator.sol file

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 interface IGenerator{
     function owner() external view returns (address);
     function matchGenerated() external view returns (string)
 }
```

Management.sol file

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "IGenerator.sol";

contract Management {
address payable immutable public manager;

string public matchDispute;

constructor(address _contract) {
    manager = payable(IGenerator(_contract).owner());
    matchDispute = IGenerator(_contract).matchGenerated();
}
```

As you can see above, I have exposed all functions of Generator that management needed and separated the definitions of the two. Try that and see if it works and if not let's know what the new error messages are.

Comment: Your solution ended in the same error but allowed me to identify the unexpected root cause: using the constructor. When I changed it to a regular public function it worked. No idea what's the real issue behind it but for now it's good enough, using a function for that makes more sense in this project, since the constructor will only be used one time and I wish to add further more matches. Thanks!